# Disabling website to everyone except portal administrators or host users in DotNetNuke 7?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7, maintenance-mode

Is it possible to disable a DNN portal, or an entire DNN installation to everyone except administrator / host users?

I need to update a DNN website and apply new themes to differant sections of the website, however this will take some time on the live website.

I'd like to achieve similar to this "**[Wordpress Maintenance Mode](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-maintenance-mode/)**" module plugin.

I'm aware of using the **APP_OFFLINE.html** file to disable the entire website, however we need a couple of admins to go in and make changes whilst keeping everyone else off the website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a maintenance mode in DNN. What I would do is the following.

Setup a new website in IIS, beta.mywebsite.com. Have that website point to your Existing DNN folder.

Point your current website to a new folder with the App_Offline.htm file/message in place. Then have your admins go to the beta.mywebsite.com URL instead of going to the www version of the URL.

That would probably be the most straightforward way to do this for DNN without writing a custom maintenance mode module for DNN.

Comment: +1 for working solution.  The original idea seems like a good idea. Do you think this is something worth creating an improvement request for through the DNN jira?  There are those who don't have that level of access to their hosted sites in IIS.

Comment: This solution will work for me, thank you Chris. I do agree with @J King though, a lot of people wouldn't have root access to their hosting.

Comment: I would agree that this would be a great feature, though I would add it to the Community Voice, as it is a feature request. I tried to add it myself, but I don't have enough "votes" due to a bug on the site...